# Is there a way to make a type variable in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am curious about a way to make a type variable.
What I mean by that is explained in the code below:

```
using var = type_var<int>; // currently var is of type type_var<int>

/// somewhere like in constexpr functions
var::store<float>;         // now var is of type type_var<float>
static_assert(std::is_same<var::get_type, float>::value, "");
```

Of course, as far as I know, this code will never work, since `using` will make `var` 'immutable'.

But still, I wonder if there is a way to store types mutably.

Comment: What do you propose to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel First, just curious. Second, it might be useful in constexpr function loops with type containers. Well, I was really just curious.

Comment: `std::variant<int, float>`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I'd rather use `std::any` instead of that in this case. Also, the variant type itself doesn't contain information of which type it holds. Or does it?

Comment: @user5876164 [`std::variant::index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Well that returns the index, not the type. The problem with that would be I should store all the types in some way to get a map from index to type. That might not be possible in some situations, so I don't think this would help to solve the problem.

Comment: Not possible. There is only [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information). How would this even work though? Even a `constexpr` function must be callable at runtime, so if this did somehow exist there would have to be a drop-in runtime replacement.

Comment: "it might be useful in constexpr function loops with type containers"  sounds like a XY-problem.  Please describe the actual use case.

Comment: what about: `std::holds_alternative` That will check if a `std::variant` hold a given type.

Comment: BTW: static_assert can not check for runtime. So you have to decide if you want to have a var which can change type by runtime or you want a compile time solution.

Comment: @L.F. I haven't thought about specific examples. I was wondering why all types are 'immutable' in the sense that, at least from my experience, there is no compile time element that can store types and modify stored types in compile time.

Comment: @super So do you mean there is no way to make an element that stores types and modifies stored types in compile time?

Comment: Because I can't think of why you want to make type mutable ...  At least not without a specific use case.

Comment: @Klaus In the code `std::variant<int,float> v=12;` `v` contains the type `int`, but the type of `v` is `std::variant<int,float>`. I wonder if there is a way to store type in some type and also modify stored type in compile time.

Comment: @L.F. There are mutable and immutable variables in most programming languages. Then why not types? That question just came to my mind. It's not that I would like to make such element and use it, but I really was just curious.

Comment: You get a lot of information and hints now. Why you still "I wonder if there is a way "... ? Don't wonder, read and understand! `std::variant` is nothing complicated, it is simply a union with a tag variable. So it simply stores different things on the same place and keep track of what type was stored last. Such simple things can be used since the first day of c++, even if `std::variant` was introduced to STL very late. And about: "int, but the type of v is std::variant<int,float>". What you want to tell us? std::vector<int> also stores int and is of type std::vector<int>. :-)

Comment: @Klaus I think we are talking about different concepts. Yes, `std::variant<args...>` stores the 'value' of the type among `args...`. What I am asking in this question is, is there a way to make an element that stores 'type' which type contained in the element can change in compile time. It seems like most of comments here are saying no for this, but there might be a way :D

Comment: Wouldn't a simple union with a type discriminant (I think is the term) do it? (Actually, the type-unsafe C variant -- so your objections apply.)

Comment: Also be sure whether you mean *compile time* (there templates are exactly what you need) and *run time* (your variable needs to have a dynamically changeable type, as opposed to a template which is just a notational convenience, in the end). Your example is entirely compile-time dependent.

Comment: It's probably possible to do what you want, but the solution is going to be ridiculously obscure. Check out https://github.com/DaemonSnake/unconstexpr

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's not what I was looking for, but it's very interesting!

Comment: @user5876164 Look at the last example in the readme. It's not exactly what you asked for, but I believe it could be adapted to suit your needs.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It is less obscure as it looks. the vars are not compile time constants, the instances of "any" are all different types, simply template instances and the "obscure" variables are template instances with a unique integer number, as this each one is its own instance and nothing breaks ODR.

Comment: @Klaus I more or less understand the underlying mechanisms, yes. But still, implementing such thing is not easy, at least for me. Stateful template metaprogramming is weird. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I am asking in this question is, is there a way to make an element that stores 'type' which type contained in the element can change in compile time.

The simple answer is No!

The c++ programming language did not have something like "compile time variables". All and everything follows the [One Definition Rule (ODR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

C++ offers with [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) a own kind of compile time language, often named as [Template MetaProgramming (TMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) The TMP language uses the general concept of a [functional programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Taken from the above linked text:

> Functional programs do not have assignment statements, that is, the value of a variable in a functional program never changes once defined.

If I understand your pseudo example code, you think something like the following:

```
template < auto x >
struct Variable
{
    static constexpr decltype(x) value = x;
};

Variable< 10 > intvar;
Variable< 'a' > charvar;

int main()
{
    // accessing the data:
    std::cout << intvar.value << std::endl;
    std::cout << charvar.value << std::endl;
}
```

But in the world of templates and types you have no chance to "assign" a new value nor type to the template anymore, simply by not having any kind of syntax for it.

You can program also algorithms in TMP, but all the "results" of "calls" are not in any kind variable, they always define new "values".

Example of some template metaprogramming. The example shows how to write a
"add" "function". It will add two type containers...

```
// define a data structure which can contain a list of types
template < typename ... TYPES >
struct TypeContainer;

// let us define some TMP "variables", which are types in c++ 
using list1 = TypeContainer<int, float, int >;
using list2 = TypeContainer< char, bool, int >;

// and now we define a TMP "function"
template < typename ... PARMS > struct Concat;

// which simply adds two typelists
template < typename ... LIST1, typename ... LIST2 >
struct Concat< TypeContainer< LIST1... >, TypeContainer< LIST2...>>
{
    using RESULT = TypeContainer< LIST1..., LIST2...>;
};

using list3 = Concat<list1, list2 >::RESULT;

// But you never can change the "variable", because of the 
// One Definition Rule (ODR)
// ( will fail to compile )
//using list2 = Concat<list1, list2 >::RESULT;

// helper to let us know what we have in the typelists:
// works for gcc or clang but is implementation specific
template < typename T>
void Print()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Print<list3>();
}
```

You will find such algorithms already defined in the STL. There you have [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) as the type container and [std::tuple_cat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) to do the "add" of two tuples. My code should only give you simple example to understand what we are doing without doing some magic things from inside the STL.